# Prerendering React app with compressed (gzip) sources with use of react-snap

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gzip, react-snap

I am trying to prerender my `react` app with `react-snap`. My project is not using `create-react-app`.

```json
// react-snap configuration
{
    inlineCss: true,
    source: "dist",
    skipThirdPartyRequests: true
}
```

Prerendering worked correctly if I built my application with `webpack` `mode: development`. But it does not when I use my production build. After spent some time debugging, I discovered, that problem happened only when I use `compression-webpack-plugin`. When I commented on it out, it finished successfully.

```js
/// webpack.config.prod.babel.js

/* eslint-disable import/default */
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import CompressionPlugin from 'compression-webpack-plugin';

import common from './webpack.config.common.babel';

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
    return merge(common(env), {
        mode: 'production',
        devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
        plugins: [
            /* when I uncomment the use of plugin, the prerendering stops to work */
            // new CompressionPlugin({
            //     algorithm: 'gzip',
            //     compressionOptions: {level: 9},
            //     test: /\.css$|\.js$|\.map|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.eot$/,
            //     threshold: 2 * 1024,
            //     deleteOriginalAssets: true
            // })
        ]
    });
};
```

The error reported by react-snap:
`pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

I figured out, that it tries to get my built `main` or `vendor` javascript file with extension `.min.js`. But in my built, there is only file with extension `.min.js.gz`, which is successfully handled with a standard request from the browser.

My production build is working correctly without prerendering. So I suppose it is a problem of some `react-snap` configuration, but I did not find any solution for it.

It is possible to use `react-snap` and gzipped sources at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `deleteOriginalAssets: true` option, without it `CompressionPlugin` should preserve the original `.min.js` files for you to use with `react-snap`. While your server will continue serve browsers with the `.min.js.gz` files because they still exist.

Comment: Good point. It is not perfect as in my final build I will have also zipped and not zipped files, but at least it is working. Thanks.